# enable curl_exec on php.ini

Tags: curl, centos, php

I wanna run php script which has got curl on it.

but following functions are disabled by php.ini:

**exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,show_source**

I have changed following line in php.ini:

**disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,show_source**

and run **service httpd restart** command on ssh,but when I run `phpinfo()` function it will show curl_exec and curl_multi_exec are disabled again.

where is the problem and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line php may be using a different ini file to the one loaded up by Apache.

you must be find which php configuration in used. you need to edit current configuration file.

```
$> php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
$> vim /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

and remove disabled function. and final step is :

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: Quick word of caution: The command line php may be using a different ini file to the one loaded up by Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the end of php.ini, and find the following line:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source;
```

Just edit it like this:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are kloxo user then you can follow these steps to enable curl.

http://www.bloggertale.com/2013/10/22/enable-curl-kloxo/

or if you are not using kloxo then login with in your root directory then go to

/etc

at there you will get php.ini

As i know that there is 2 lines

```
exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,show_source
```

mean one is middle of php.ini and then in last one.  You have to Remove from both place.

**First** :- search `curl_exec,curl_multi_exec` and you will get this line in two place just remove it and save the php.ini and then

Use this command :- `service httpd restart`

Then create a file

info.php

and write this code to get the status of curl

```
<?=phpinfo();?>
```

At their you will able to see **CURL IS ENABLE**.

Answer (score -1):

Just uncomment this line in your php.ini file

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

and restart your server.

Comment: If the functions are shown as disabled in phpinfo, that's not because of the extension being disabled.

Answer (score -1):

First of all please check permission for php.ini ,this must be writable.
then go to php.ini and find line

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

and remove `;` for uncomment it. and then restart your xampp or wamp server. Please try this change and if get any further problem let me know.

thanks.

Comment: i think in Centos you have to installed curl module, I am not confirm but i have read sometime before it, so please check about that may be a issue... thanks..