# Tweet by PHP, forbidden?

Tags: php, twitter

```
<?php

// Set username and password
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXX';
// The message you want to send
$message = 'is twittering from php using curl';
// The twitter API address
$url = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';
// Alternative JSON version
// $url = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json';
// Set up and execute the curl process
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
// check for success or failure
if (empty($buffer)) {
    echo 'failure';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}

echo $buffer;

?>
```

Hallo, I have an Problem with the Code above. I have it from an Website. It returns at $buffer, that the Server understood the request but is an forbidden one.

Comment: Please show us the Complete error message, not a summary

Answer (score 3):

The Twitter API does not support Tweeting with a username and password, you need to use OAuth. Also, the Twitter API URL that you are using in this code is very old (like, about 14 years old). You need to use the [official Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com). There are some [current PHP libraries available](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries).

Answer (score -2):

It's probably disabled within your server's configuration file. You should look into your specific server settings and fiddle around, `curl_exec` might be disabled by default.

You can check if the setting is enabled using the following command;

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you need help with configuring the `php.ini` file, please check this topic; [enable curl_exec on php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310193/enable-curl-exec-on-php-ini). You would have to look for a line with `disabled_functions`, `curl_exec` might be added there.

Comment: 403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Comment: So it is today only possible with the API?

Comment: No sorry, I thought it was your apache instance causing the error.

Comment: Yes, it is only possible with the API.